# Ошибка "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 38: invalid start byte" при попытке с компилировать движок V8

Tags: c++, v8

Хочу скомпилировать движок V8. Скачал все необходимое, включая `depot_tools`. Запускаю `gclient`, жду пока он скачает дополнительные инструменты и получаю следующую ошибку:

```
PS D:\v8> gclient
Downloading CIPD client for windows-amd64 from https://chrome-infra-packages.appspot.com/client?platform=windows-amd64&version=git_revision:8e9b0c80860d00dfe951f7ea37d74e210d376c13...
[E2022-03-11T17:44:35.838338+03:00 21208 0 venv.go:994] Command (cwd=C:\Users\CD86~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vpython_bootstrap803694508\packages\virtualenv-16.7.10): [D:\v8\depot_tools\bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin\python3\bin\python3.exe -B -E -s virtualenv.py --no-download C:\Users\Алексей\.vpython-root\b061f6]
Process output:
Using base prefix 'D:\\v8\\depot_tools\\bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin\\python3\\bin'
New python executable in C:\Users\�������\.vpython-root\b061f6\Scripts\python3.exe
Also creating executable in C:\Users\�������\.vpython-root\b061f6\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "virtualenv.py", line 938, in call_subprocess
    line = line.decode(encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 38: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "virtualenv.py", line 2651, in <module>
    main()
  File "virtualenv.py", line 859, in main
    create_environment(
  File "virtualenv.py", line 1178, in create_environment
    install_wheel(to_install, py_executable, search_dirs, download=download)
  File "virtualenv.py", line 1022, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel_with_search_dir(download, project_names, py_executable, search_dirs)
  File "virtualenv.py", line 1115, in _install_wheel_with_search_dir
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=script)
  File "virtualenv.py", line 940, in call_subprocess
    line = line.decode(fs_encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 38: invalid start byte

Environment:
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
ANDROID_AVD_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk
ANDROID_HOME=D:\android-sdk
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=D:\android-sdk
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=D:\android-sdk
APPDATA=C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Roaming
CARGO_HOME=D:\RustLang\Cargo
CLion=D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin;
COMPUTERNAME=DESKTOP-U6B8I6T
CUDA_PATH=D:\CUDA
CUDA_PATH_V10_1=D:\CUDA
ChocolateyInstall=C:\ProgramData\chocolatey
ChocolateyLastPathUpdate=132740182193593701
ChocolateyToolsLocation=C:\tools
ComSpec=C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
EXPORT_ERRORLEVEL=0
GOPATH=C:\Users\Алексей\go
GTK_BASEPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\
GoLand=D:\GoLand 2021.2.1\bin;
Gradle=D:\Gradle\bin\gradle.bat
HOME=C:\Users\CD86~1\AppData\Local\Temp\vpython_bootstrap803694508
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Алексей
INTEL_DEV_REDIST=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\
IntelliJ IDEA=D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1\bin;
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11
JetBrains Rider=D:\JetBrains Rider 2021.3.2\bin;
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\DESKTOP-U6B8I6T
MIC_LD_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\compiler\lib\intel64_win_mic
MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH=D:\Foxit Reader\plugins\
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
NVCUDASAMPLES10_1_ROOT=D:\CUDA
NVCUDASAMPLES_ROOT=D:\CUDA
NVIDIAWHITELISTED=0x01
NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
OS=Windows_NT
OneDrive=C:\Users\Алексей\OneDrive
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
PIP_NO_BINARY=:none:
PIP_ONLY_BINARY=:all:
POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL=MSI:Windows 10 Enterprise
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 23 Model 24 Stepping 1, AuthenticAMD
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=23
PROCESSOR_REVISION=1801
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Users\Алексей\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
PYTHON3_BIN_RELDIR=bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin\python3\bin
PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1
PYTHON_HOME=D:\Python
Path=D:\v8\depot_tools\bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin\python3\bin;D:\v8\depot_tools\bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin\python3\bin\Scripts;D:\v8\depot_tools\bootstrap-2@3_8_10_chromium_23_bin\python3\bin\DLLs;D:\v8\depot_tools\;D:\VMWare Workstation\bin\;D:\CUDA\bin;D:\CUDA\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\APIs\Python\Scripts\;D:\APIs\Python\;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;D:\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;D:\Python;D:\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;D:\MinGW\bin;D:\CMake\bin;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;D:\Maven\bin;C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin;C:\tools\flutter;D:\MinGW;D:\Gradle\gradle-6.7.1\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;D:\Win-builds\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Azure Data Studio\bin;D:\APIs\GoLang\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;D:\MongoDB\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin;D:\APIs\dex2jar-2.x\dex2jar-2.0;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;D:\APIs\NodeJS\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2019.4.0\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\SnapAPI\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\VirtualFile\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Acronis\VirtualFile64\;D:\RustLang\Cargo\bin;C:\Users\Алексей\.cargo\bin;D:\APIS\Scripts\;D:\APIS\;C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\PhpStorm 2019.2.3\bin;D:\JetBrains Rider 2020.1.1\bin;D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.6\bin;D:\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\CLion 2019.3.2\bin;D:\PyCharm 2019.3.1\bin;D:\PhoenixSuit_V1.10\;C:\Users\Алексей\.dotnet\tools;D:\CLion 2021.3.3\bin;C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;D:\PyCharm 2021.3.2\bin;D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1\bin;D:\MikTeX\miktex\bin\x64\;C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin;C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\bin;C:\tools\flutter\bin;C:\Users\Алексей\.dotnet\tools;D:\JetBrains Rider 2021.3.2\bin;C:\tools\neovim\Neovim\bin;D:\WebStorm 2020.3.3\bin;C:\Users\Алексей\go\bin;D:\GoLand 2021.2.1\bin;C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\v8\depot_tools\
PhoenixPath=D:\PhoenixSuit_V1.10\
PhpStorm=D:\PhpStorm 2019.2.3\bin;
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PyCharm=D:\PyCharm 2021.3.2\bin;
QtMsBuild=C:\Users\Алексей\AppData\Local\QtMsBuild
RUSTUP_HOME=D:\RustLang\RustUP
SHIM_MCCOMPAT=0x810000001
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
TEMP=C:\Users\CD86~1\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\CD86~1\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=DESKTOP-U6B8I6T
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DESKTOP-U6B8I6T
USERNAME=Alexey
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Алексей
VBOX_HWVIRTEX_IGNORE_SVM_IN_USE=1
WSLENV=WT_SESSION::WT_PROFILE_ID
WT_PROFILE_ID={61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}
WT_SESSION=cecf6f2f-c682-4cfc-bff5-167e8bf05f4a
WebStorm=D:\WebStorm 2020.3.3\bin;
windir=C:\WINDOWS
[E2022-03-11T17:44:35.878128+03:00 21208 0 annotate.go:273] original error: exit status 1

goroutine 1:
#0 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:622 - venv.(*Env).installVirtualEnv()
  reason: failed to create VirtualEnv

#1 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:536 - venv.(*Env).createLocked.func2()
  reason: failed to install VirtualEnv

#2 go.chromium.org/luci/common/system/filesystem/tempdir.go:55 - filesystem.(*TempDir).With()
#3 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:103 - venv.withTempDir()
#4 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:522 - venv.(*Env).createLocked()
#5 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:279 - venv.(*Env).ensure.func1()
  reason: failed to create new VirtualEnv

#6 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:1014 - venv.mustReleaseLock()
#7 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:265 - venv.(*Env).ensure()
#8 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:161 - venv.With()
  reason: failed to create empty probe environment

#9 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/run.go:60 - vpython.Run()
#10 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:327 - application.(*application).mainImpl()
#11 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:416 - application.(*Config).Main.func1()
#12 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/support.go:46 - application.run()
#13 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:415 - application.(*Config).Main()
#14 vpython/main.go:112 - main.mainImpl()
#15 vpython/main.go:118 - main.main()
#16 runtime/proc.go:225 - runtime.main()
#17 runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371 - runtime.goexit()
```

Кто-то сталкивался с такой ошибкой? Может ли она возникать из-за того, что папка пользователя у меня на русском?

Comment: Именно из за этого оно и происходит. Но только имя у Вас не на русском, а кириллицей.

Comment: @KoVadim, спасибо, можете оформить это как ответ, но тогда как изменить имя папки пользователя?

Comment: А кто Вам мешает создать новую папку прямо в корне диска и туда все переместить? Пользователя можно переименовать, но обычно после этого бывают разнообразные постеэффекты. Легче нового пользователя создать.

Comment: @KoVadim, я вас понял, спасибо